# Are software like NTRconnect and LogMeIn safe enough for businesses with sensitive data?

Tags: logmein

I am thinking about creating a VPN using NTRconnect or LogMeIn. Are these softwares safe? We spent money erecting firewalls, but are those software going to undo the protections? Are there known vulnerabilities?

Comment: Is there any additional information I can provide to get this question marked answered?

Comment: I was more concerned about security. Can it be exploited by hackers to get past the firewall etc.

Comment: I updated the information regarding security. Hopefully it will be sufficient to close this question.

Answer (score 5):

I have about 30 offices connected through LogMeIn Central (which is about 200 computers). When I log into their site, an email is dispatched to my phone with an 8 digit/character randomly generated value. I have to enter that value before I can access my account. I find this to be extremely secure.

Also, LogMeIn is a very reputable company and is used by companies such as SonicWall for their technical support team. I was surprised when I had a technical problem with SonicWall and their tech connected to me via LogMeIn. I expect that a lot of companies will be migrating from WebEx to LogMeIn over the next couple years.

I use the paid version of LogMeIn (LogMeIn123 and LogMeIn Central). However, I still use the FREE version of the daemon on the client computers. Annual fee for LogMeIn Central is about $250, while LogMeIn123 has a monthly fee of about $110.

Update: Their website states, "All communications by LogMeIn products use industry-standard algorithms and protocols for encryption and authentication. Nobody will be able to see or access the data transmitted between your computers - not even us." More information about their security and encryption is available at https://secure.logmein.com/products/central/security.aspx

Comment: But is the connection easy to "hack" into? I mean what if the data is really sensitive and contains private customer information?

Comment: Like anything, there is a key for every lock.... someone out there may be brilliant enough to hack it. I tried googling for "LogMeIn" hacks, but did not find anything out there that is publicly known. If you are extremely paranoid, you could activate Remote Desktop on your customers computers and run them through a Remote Desktop Gateway Server... I'd be more than happy to provide you with more information on that if you are interested.